# Left join on multiple column performance?

Tags: mysql, performance, left-join

Assume that I have 2 tables :

```
table1 :(20.000 records)
id    code1    code2   something    status

table2: (7.500 records)
id    code1    code2    name
```

All I want is list all records in table1 with the "name" in table2 by using this QUERY:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `tb1`.*, `tb2`.`name` FROM `table1` AS `tb1`
LEFT JOIN `table2` AS `tb2`
ON (tb1.code1 = tb2.code1 AND tb1.code2 = tb2.code2)
WHERE (tb1.status = 1)
```

But it took me too long to retreive the data (after 5 minutes I still cant see the result).

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Why are you doing a LEFT JOIN when you only want records with a certain status of the right-hand table? Just do an INNER JOIN, and check that your tables have appropriate indexes.

Comment: Oops, my typo mistake. Sorry :D . I updated my question

Comment: Are you sure your data is as you expect? Are there multiple rows in table2 with the same code1 and code2 (eg multiple rows where code1='abc' and code2='def')? If it's taking >5 minutes you must be pulling back a HEAP of rows.

Comment: @mwan Yes, rows with [code1, code2] in table2 are unique

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try adding an index on table1 using columns(code1,code2,status). If you don't have too many columns in table1, you can add them to the index too. In MS SQL, we have "include columns" that we can add to an index. Maybe mysql has something similar.

Add an index on table2 using columns(code1,code2, name).

If you are concerned about index size then just keep (code1, code2, status) for index1 and (code1, code2) for index2.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Nahbeet Can you give a code example of how to use the index for the left join? I have the same issue but can't find documentation on this operation.